# Factoring a polynomial to get its zeros

Tags: polynomials, factoring

While studying about sums and products of roots of polynomials, I found this on the web:

> We can take a polynomial, such as:
>   $$f(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 +\dots$$
>   And then factor it like this:
>   $$f(x) = a(x−p)(x−q)(x−r)\dots$$
>   Then $p, q, r$, etc are the roots (where the polynomial equals zero)

My question is as follows: Why is there an '$a$' in the given statement
$$f(x) = \mathbf a(x−p)(x−q)(x−r)\dots$$

*If anything is unclear, ask me to edit the question in comments.*

Comment: What difference would it make without the $a$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there wouldn't be an $a$, the leading term (which you get by multiplying all the $x$-es together) would be $x^4$, not $ax^4$.